# Best Way to handle Bulk Mail in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, email, sendgrid

What would be the best method to send bulk emails to certain lists. E.g. a user would request a service from a service category. I get 200-20000 matching emails for the users criteria and send the users request to the recipients.

I have done some research but not sure which would be the best solution for the task.

Method 1, use multiple threads to enable multiple SMTP clients to send mails (not sure if I send it to a massive amount of recipients if it would kill the server with all the threads) http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-Bulk-Mass-Email-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Method 2, use service like sendgrid to manage the emails. (I see that in the marketing campaigns you can manage lists/contacts. Just not sure if you can dynamically generate the content for a template and send to the certain list) https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Its just my opinion, I don't recommend the first method, since it might ends with all your mails go to the spam or junk mails which I faced it before, 2nd step, you will use a third party solution which might be down someday or they change the configurations that might effect your setup and you don't know about it, in case you don't have notifications that the service is not working. IMO, there is another method if you are using Database Management System, in my case I am using MS-SQL Server, as mentioned in the answer below, if you want further help you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

You have many different ways

The first way, which we use it and in my opinion is the best, but you need to use a database to store the data and to write some code to be executed:

1. Create a table "EmailLogs" with the following fields

> ProfileName, Body, Subject, [To],CC,BCC,IsActive,QueuedOn,SentOn

2. Write a Stored Procedure ClearEmailLogs to send top 50 where `IsActive=1` and update the SentOn by `getdate()` value
3. Write a Job in SQL server to execute each 10 minutes
4. From your application, you just need to insert the bulk of messages to the table EmailLogs

ProfileName: maybe you need to have many emails configuration to send through different emails for example `noreply@yourdomain.com` or `info@yourdomain.com`, in SQL server you can create profile for each email you want to use

Why to send max 50 email each 10 minutes? because if you will send frequently emails to recipients, other companies like yahoo or google...etc might block your emails and send them to the spam or junk mails.

second way, you can subscribe to some services, you can find online, but you need to pay some money for this service.

Hope this will helped you

Comment: What's the reason of putting all the application logic into speed procedures on the SQL server? That's horribly bad for many many reasons and there doesn't seem to be anything in particular that would require such a weird design. This doesn't even deal with the sending emails part at all, just a different way to organize the code.

Comment: :O WHAT? if you want to send 1000 emails, is it logic to let your application to execute them? and what is the "horribly bad" in this scenario? if there is something bad in SP, why did they create something called stored procedure then and what is the role for it?

Comment: @Voo kindly explain your down vote and what is the problem of using this solution which is already in use and it proved its performance and how easy it is.

Comment: Your answer to "How to do X in C#" is basically "Implement the application logic in TSQL" without even mentioning how to solve the actual problem (the email sending). Step 3 would be what this question is all about after all, but it glosses over all the details - how to write such a job? use multiple threads? how to handle and communicate errors? But if you can explain what balances out all the all the downsides of using TSQL (no portability, maintenance troubles, bad debugging tools, very limited concurrency tools, C# devs [see tag] now having to write TSQL) it'd be at least interesting

Comment: I used to look to the questions and directly provide the solution in order to help the person who asked the question, today I get new tip, that some questions should be dedicated as the tags mentioned, I assumed he is using C# and ASP.NET, this means he is using a Database, so I can provide a solution for his case, thank you

Comment: Typically, email sending is an application concern. Implementing it as an SQL server job sounds like an architectural smell. Additional downsides with the approach: (a) wasting DB server resources for functions which are completely irrelevant with the database (b) you are going to have a very weird discussion when someone asks 'how does your application scale'.